# Download Django 1.3 Official Release Fail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, django

When I try to download the 1.3 version of Django in Ubuntu 10.4, it saves it as index.html.

```
  wget http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3/tarball/
```

I've done this successfully in the past. Python2.6 is installed. No previous versions of django are installed.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the URL and using the -O option to define output file, or in other words

```
wget "http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3/tarball/" -O django.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mv index.html Django-1.3.tar.gz
```

That said, working fine here.